# cygwin gcc/g++ compiling shared library undefined reference to extern function

Tags: unix, gcc, linker, cygwin

I am compiling a huge library. For that I am using Makefile, the final library should be `.so`.
The `main()` function is inside library.
 I have some functions which are declared as - `extern void func(void);` The bodies of that functions should be inside the program which is using that library. The program should be consist of only that extern functions.

When I compile the library I get error

> undefined reference to `func()'

Makefile option is

```
gcc -shared -o $@ $% $(LIBRARYOBJ)
```

LIBRARYOBJ is names of my files.

What am I doing wrong ? Why it brings that error if I am compiling library only?
As I know linker should not bring error for extern funktions during compilation.

Comment: It is unusual to build a library that contains `main()`. The `gcc` linker seems to assume that if the collection of object files contains `main()`, the desired product is an executable, not a library.

Comment: ok, thanks,  yes seems similar. And is there any solution, any way to explain linker that it is a library not executable ?

Comment: Although it's not good practice to put main() inside shared library, it should not cause build issue.  To get rid of undefined reference error, please try to add the shared library including func() into build, like "gcc -shared -o $@ $% $(LIBRARAYOBJ) <shared library including func()>" or using "-L" and "-l" option.

Comment: You need to post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MikeKinghan: I'm a big fan of MVCEs, but I was able to reproduce this problem with little more than HelloWorld. (If I knew how to solve it, I'd post an Answer.)